# visual studio post-build script error calling gacutil

Tags: visual-studio-2005, gacutil, build-script

I'm on vista, with VS2005 running as admin.  Both vs2005 and vs2008 are installed.  If I explicitly use the path to gacutil, it works, but not if I only call gacutil like this:

```
if NOT $(ConfigurationName) == Release gacutil /f /i "$(TargetPath)"
```

I would just update the post-build script, but I've been asked to leave it alone.  It's a project for a sister company.  The path to gacutil is in Visual Studio environment variables, so it should be able to find it.  (Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VC++ Directories)

Is there some way to tweak visual studio or windows environment variable to get the above post-build script to work?  I need to it to build, because it's a dependency of a project I need to code.

TIA, -j

Comment: How are you using the build? Are you using msbuild or calling devenv from the command line or are you building this right in the IDE?

Answer (score 1):

As you suggest, tweaking the Windows PATH environment variable should get things working.
append the directory that contains GACUTIL to the end of the PATH. For example, using the location on my computer, append (without the quotes) ";C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin" to the existing value of the PATH system environment variable.
Restart Visual Studio to pick up the new value.

Dave